# how to show the next card like this and show only one card in the screen?(attached screenshot of UI)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I designed the entire card. But I don't understand how to show the next card like this and how to show only one card on the screen?

I want is like the below image, but I have failed till now. Any help would be appreciated. Below is the code I have did so far.

Thanks.

```
PageView.builder(
   scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
   physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
   reverse: true,
   controller: controller,
   itemCount: 10,
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int position) {

//previous screen showing, If the page is the page being swiped from

if (position == currentPageValue.floor()) {
  return Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(currentPageValue - position),
    child: Container(
      color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
        child: Center(
          child: Text("Page if $position ${currentPageValue.floor()}",
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0)),
        ),
    ),
  );
} 

//after scroll, If the page is the page being swiped to

else if (position == currentPageValue.floor() + 1){
  return Transform(
    transform: Matrix4.identity()..rotateX(currentPageValue - position),
    child: Container(color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
       child: Center(
          child: Text("Page$position ${currentPageValue.floor()+1}",
                 style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0)),
       ),
    ),
  );
}

//If the page is a page off screen

else {
   return Container(color: position % 2 == 0 ? Colors.blue : Colors.pink,
     child: Center(
        child: Text("Page$position",
               style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 22.0)),
     ),
   );
}
}),
```

please check I need like this card

[image: please check I need like this card]
current progress-- I need to show next page card on main screen

[image: this]

Comment: /what you have tried so far? put some code there

Comment: i tried, but is not like ui

Comment: I am asking what you have tried? any code to show their, any part of that UI you have achieved so far?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman please check question I edited

Comment: I still didn't understand, there is a lot of difference in both the images? What you want as a final thing?

Comment: @MuhammadNoman sorry about my English..I modified please check

Comment: means you want to show card on hover of that previous card, looks like its behind that

Comment: like this https://dribbble.com/shots/3593825-Android-Card-Slider-Preview-Open-Source

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use a [PageView](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J1gE9xvph-A)

Comment: I already used pageView..please check question. I need to know how to show next card on main menu

Comment: Ok, I see you are following this tutorial https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded. Did you follow all the steps including "Updating the variable when the PageView is scrolled." where controller.addListener is defined?

Comment: inside build method